# Сортировка списка в обратном порядке по дате

Tags: java, java-stream

***Нужно вернуть список еды сортированный в обратном порядке по датам, IDEA ругается в sorted().
Как правильно написать стрим?***

```
private final Map<Integer,Meal> repository = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

@Override
    public Collection<Meal> getAll() {
        return repository.entrySet().stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Meal::getDateTime).reversed()) //
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
```

Required type: Comparator <? super Entry<Integer, Meal>>
Provided: Comparator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return repository.entrySet().stream().map(e -> e.getValue())
        .sorted(...
```

Comment: Короче и правильлней (меньше гетеров) будет:  repository.values().stream().sorted(...

Comment: Благодарю за ответы !

Comment: @KanariHimawari Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.